# Hello. Im trying to make a pyramid of strings with my name in it

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        string st("HabibRehman");
        string a="", b="";
        int y=st.length();
        int d=y/2;
        int f;
        f=d;
        for(int i=1;i<st.length();i++){
            for( int j=0;j<y;j++){
                cout<<" ";
            }
            for(int k=0;k<1;k++)/*I'm not sure what this loop should be*/{
                cout<<a+st.substr(d,i)<<endl;
                /*int d=(st.length()/2);
                static int f=d;//I was trying to keep the values static here
                static int g=d;*/
                //this doesn't work in here

            }
            --f;//if i put this outside the for loop it works wrong without the termination error.
            a=st.substr(f,i);//I'm using this to get the value prior to the st.substr(d,i)
            y--;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I keep getting a termination error. Ive tried almost everything I knew like changing the loops, the positions of substrings and variables, when I get the output I want, the program gives me an termination error, otherwise it gives me a wrong output without the termination error.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. I think the image is missing.

Comment: `[the image shows the error I keep getting]` will emit compile error. When it is removed, `f` will go negative and it will cause out of range error.

Comment: Do not add textual output as an image to your post! Just [edit] it as text in your question (and in the proper place, please).

Comment: this is the error I get: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting.  Habib, here is [some advice](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Jorf I'm not asking someone to debug my code, I'm just getting a termination error that I'm not familiar with. My output is correct.

Comment: The error message tells you a lot, doesn't it? You're passing an invalid value for the first parameter of a call to `substr`. (And of course you know that 2 to the power of 64 is 18446744073709551616, so that weird number isn't that weird.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not fully understand this code, it really writed very bad.

But after 1,5 minutes of debugging I found that exception is thrown because `f` in `a=st.substr(f,i);` is lower than 0.

In `for(int i=1;i<st.length();i++){` you decrement the variable `f` `st.length()` times, but `f` is half of `st.length()` and will get after `st.length()/2` iterations `-1` value.

I added after `--f;`
this statement:

`if(f < 0 ) return 0;`

and it seems that programm working well.

Please, learn how to write beatiful and readable code.